# MySQL MEMORY @@max_heap_table_size not noticed in batch file

Tags: mysql

I had a table that was larger than 16MB so I hit ERROR 1114: The table xxx is full. when doing a

```
    CREATE tableX engine=memory SELECT * from tableY;
```

So in Workbench I duly entered

```
    set@@max_heap_table_size = 64000000;
```

and then my CREATE worked fine.

However, when I migrated the process to be called by a batch file, MySQL still thinks my table is 16MB.

Confused I am, but I am sure it is a lack of understanding of the architecture of MySQL on my part.  Advice from anybody in the know out there, would be greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: I also think part of my problem was that I was trying to set my max_heap_table using a -e switch from a command line call of mySQL.  When I logged into an actual MySQL prompt and ran the set command, then it worked.

Comment: I do take on board your comment @Mchl -  I understand what you are telling me in that I need to update a config file if I want the new max_heap_table_size parameter to remain permanent.  As I had neither a my.cnf nor a my.ini file, I took the my-innodb-heavy-4G.ini and copied it to my.ini. I took this file as it specifically referenced the max_heap_table_size variable - would this be correct procedure?  Am I opening myself up for issues by taking this course of action, and if so, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable set this way will not persist when the server is restarted. To have it always set to this value put it in your `my.cnf`/`my.ini` file.

Comment: So after renaming the template .ini file, yes my table is now 64Mb, but I can't read my existing InnoDB tables.  If I set default-storage-engine = InnoDB (that is how it is spelt / capitalised), my MySQL service doesn't start. If I set the .ini file back to default-storage-engine=MYISAM, then the MySQL service starts and then I can see with a SHOW ENGINES that InnoDB is not available.

Comment: This probably warrants another question probably on http://dba.stackexchange.com/
However, you might want to try put your server offline, delete `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` files from MySQL's `data` folder, then start the server again. If these files grow above size set in `my.ini` (or when the size set in the file is reduced) it is known to prevent InnoDB from starting.

Comment: Thanks for more of your time!  I had tried the removing log file approach, but no joy.  I tracked it down to the innodb_buffer_pool_size.  It was set to 2G, which was simply too high for my server. I knocked it down to 512M, ensured that my default-storage-engine was InnoDB and restarted MySQL.  It worked, and my original issue with the max_heap_table_size is permanently set too!  Hurrah, and thanks.